# Retrieving entire json array as a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, fine-uploader

I am using fine uploader to pass params like this

```
callbacks: {
    onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {
        this.setParams({
            a: 'adm',
            b: '126',
            c: {
                fileID: id,
                path:'',
                name:'',
                originalName: fileName
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On the server side (in nodejs) I would like to retrieve the entire array at once
with something like

```
req.body[c]
```

to get the string

```
{
    fileID: id,
        path:'',
    name:'',
    originalName: fileName
}
```

but c comes out as a javascript array so it seems I would have to pick each subkey one by one with

```
req.body[c['fileID']], ...
```

Is there a way in javascript/fine uploader of getting the entire array by its name?

Or at least an easier way to loop through all the keys of the array?

Comment: What if you use JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse ?

Comment: Uhm, I think `req.body.c` is an object. You can use for..in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure `req.body.c` is an object, not an array.

There are various way to get all the pair keys/values from an Object.

Two of them are the [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var c = {
    fileID: 1,
    path:'',
    name:'',
    originalName: 'fileName'
}

for (let key in c) {
  if (!c.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
  console.log('Key:', key, ' value:', c[key]);
}

var keys = Object.keys(c);
console.log('Second method:');
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log('Key:', keys[i], ' value:', c[keys[i]]);
}
```

In the future you will use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (atm works in Firefox > 47 and Chrome > 51):

```
Object.entries(c).forEach(arr => console.log('Key:', arr[0], ' value:', arr[1]));
```

Comment: Thanks. Whenever I try to do req.body.c I get undefined although if I print req.body the array c is there. I must be missing something.

Comment: @user2175783 sorry, what? Where do you try to do `req.body.c`? What does it mean it is undefined? If you refer to my code, you need to replace **all** the `c` with `req.body.c`, also the ones inside the fors

Comment: When I do console.log(req.body) it prints out {a:'adm', b:'126', 'c[fileID]':'1','c[path]':' ','c[name]':' ','c[originalName]':'filename'}. req.body[c] or req.body['c'] or req.body[c] all return undefined though.

Comment: @user2175783 this is quite strange, I think you have some problems send the data, because `c` doesn't exist at all, you have some param which starts with `c`